# Inputting and storing large numbers

Tags: c++, largenumber

This is a project for a class using c++. Input must be taken from the user from the console, and must not be inputted as a string or char. External libraries not allowed, only my own code. Must be sorted in with an int type (array or pointer allowed, no vector).

Assume the user inputs a 512-digit number (such as RSA keys). The no string input or conversion is what is problematic. Is there a way to take each 9 digits of the number given to store inside a dynamic int array element?

```
std::cin >> stringNumber;
// Assume validation
int arraySize = (stringNumber.length() / 9) + 1;
int* num = new int[arraySize];
for ( int i = 0; i < (arraySize - 1); i++ ) {
    num[i] = toInt(stringNumber.substr((i * 9), 9));
}
// Sets last element, assume toInt converts numbers in string to int
num[arraySize - 1] = toInt(stringNumber.substr((arraySize - 1) * 9, (arraySize - 1) % 9);
```

The above is a quick, untested markup of how the idea works with strings, but to remove all usage of strings makes me clueless.

Comment: (and must not be inputted as a string or char) - are you sure that's the actual statement from the task? That sounds like unobtanium, unless there was some trick in wording of task. Console inherently inputs char or string - anything else is parsing within your program, using library or not. char is byte type... you may trick it by serializing series of shorts of ints, but that isn't inputting  a "large" number. RSA key is 1024 bit  long at least, you can't input that in any form because maximum what C++ standard library support is 64bit int.

Comment: @Swift What I mean by no string or char is that no variable of such type may be present. I'm looking at an older RSA, but that was just an example. This is some sort of input for these numbers without variable type conversion, to lead into arbitary precision calculator assassignment.

Comment: If you are unable to work with chars, I concur with Swift. This is not possible. Any input to a numeric type is bounded by that numeric types size and is assumed to be whitespace separated.

Comment: What the goal? If all you need is storing these large numbers then just store them as strings.

Comment: Are you allowed to separate the digits of the input by spaces? Then you could simply use `cin >> someIntVar` in a loop.

Comment: @ Captain Giraffe well, it is possible to "cheat" with `auto` and with lambda expressions , I suppose, if to follow only the letter but not spirit of the task :P I fear it may require C++14.. but maybe C++11 is enough.